# ¿Cómo indicar la fecha de vencimiento de una solicitud?

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Lo que debo hacer es indicar al usuario cuando la solicitud de prestamo de un dispositivo USB haya vencido. 
Recibo la fecha de creacion de solicitud y la fecha que se debe entregar el dispositivo, 
entonces debe ir evaluando e indicando  los días restantes para entregar el dispositivo, 
se debe ir verificando con la fecha del sistema para saber si ya llego el día de vencimiento:

Ejemplo:

> Fecha Creacion de solicitud: 01-09-2017.
>   Fecha Entrega: 04-09-2017.

Cuando en la fecha del sistema sea `04-09-2017` debo indicar que la solicitud ha vencido.

Tengo el siguiente método, pero no me funciona me envía directamente al `Catch`:

```
<?php
public function SolicitudesCaducadas ()
{
    try
    {
        $registros      = SolicitudesUsb::with('USB')->get();

        foreach ($registros as $itemNuevo) {

            $diaInicial     = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y',$itemNuevo->fechasolicitud);
            $diaInicialForm = $diaInicial->format('d/m/Y');


            $diaEntrega     = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y',$itemNuevo->fechaentrega);
            $diaEntregaForm = $diaEntrega->format('d/m/Y');

            $fechaSistema   =  Carbon::now();
            $fechaSistemaForm   = $fechaSistema->format('d/m/Y');
            //$garantia       = 5;
            $dias           = 0;

            $diferenciaDias = $diaInicial->diffInDays($diaEntrega);
            $garantia = $diferenciaDias;



            while ($diaInicialForm != $fechaSistemaForm){
                    if ($diaInicialForm->dayOfWeek != 0 && $diaInicialForm->dayOfWeek != 6) $dias++;
                    $diaInicialForm->addDay();
                }

            $itemNuevo["dias_restantes"] = $dias;

            if (($garantia - $dias) < 0)
            {
                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->records  = $registros;
                $this->message  = "Ya no tiene garantia";
                $this->result   = true;
            }
            else
            {
               if (($garantia - $dias) == 0)
               {
                    $statusCode     = 200;
                    $this->records  = $registros;
                    $this->message  = "La garantia vence hoy";
                    $this->result   = true;
               }
               else
               {
                    $statusCode     = 200;
                    $this->records  = $registros;
                    $this->message  = "Queda ".($garantia-$dias)." dias de garantia";
                    $this->result   = true;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $statusCode     = 200;
        $this->message  = "Error en el registro.";
        $this->result   = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        $response =
        [
            'message' => $this->message,
            'result'  => $this->result,
            'records' => $this->records
        ];
            return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }
}
?>
```

**¿Alguna otra solución para realizar ese proceso que necesito?**

Cuando realizo el cambio de parámetros en el `while` dejandolo de esta forma:

```
<?php
while ($diaInicial != $diaEntrega){
         if ($diaInicial->dayOfWeek != 0 && $diaInicial->dayOfWeek != 6) $dias++;
        $diaInicial->addDay();
 }
 ?>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
{
"message": "La garantia vence hoy",
"result": true,
"records": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "idusb": 2,
        "solicitante": "Prueba",
        "fechasolicitud": "28.08.2017",
        "fechaentrega": "30.08.2017",
        "created_at": "2017-08-09 21:14:30",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-09 22:36:30",
        "dias_restantes": 2,
        "u_s_b": {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "USB2",
            "estado": 2,
            "created_at": "2017-08-01 17:23:15",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-10 18:39:23"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Pero creo que no es una respuesta correcta ya que no esta evaluando la fecha del sistema.

Lo que tomé como ejemplo fue este código:

```
<?php
$fechaInicial = '12/10/2016'; //fecha de registro

$initialDay = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fechaInicial);

$warrantyDays = 5; //dias de garantia que tiene el producto
$days = 0;
$today = Carbon::now();


while ($initialDay != $today){
    if ($initialDay->dayOfWeek != 0 && $initialDay->dayOfWeek != 6) $days++;
    $initialDay->addDay();
}

if (($warrantyDays - $days) < 0) dd('Ya no tiene garantia');
else {
    if (($warrantyDays - $days) == 0) dd('La garantia vence hoy');
    else dd('Queda ' . ($warrantyDays - $days) . ' dias de garantia');
}
```

Comment: que quiere decir que no funciona? podrias ser mas claro con los problemas que tiene?

Comment: me envia directamente al Catch, no entiendo que hago mal.

Comment: ¿podemos ver un dump de la variable $registros antes del foreach?

Comment: Si, si todo bien hasta ahi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No termino de entender los **if** o por que haces algunas cosa.

Te expongo un ejemplo para calcular las fechas y hacer los if, en este caso es con la clase [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) de PHP ya que es a la que estoy acostumbrado.

```
<?php
$fechaSistema   = new \DateTime();
$diaInicial     = new \DateTime( '2017-09-01' );// setear tus fechas aqui
$diaEntrega     = new \DateTime( '2017-09-06' );// setear tus fechas aqui

$interval_now       = $fechaSistema->diff($diaEntrega);
$interval_inicial   = $diaInicial->diff($diaEntrega);

$dias_restantes = $interval_now->format('%R%a');
$total_dias     = $interval_inicial->format('%R%a');

if ( $dias_restantes < 0)
{
    // si se ha superado la fecha de entrega
    echo "Ya no tiene garantia";
}
elseif ( $dias_restantes == 0)
{
    // "La garantia vence hoy"
    echo "La garantia vence hoy";
}
else
{
    // "La garantia vence hoy"
    echo 'Queda '.$dias_restantes .' días de garantía.';
}
```

Adaptandolo a tu código:

```
<?php

public function SolicitudesCaducadas ()
{
    try
    {
        $registros = SolicitudesUsb::with('USB')->get();

        foreach ($registros as $itemNuevo) {


            $fechaSistema   = new \DateTime();
            $diaInicial     = new \DateTime( $itemNuevo->fechasolicitud );
            $diaEntrega     = new \DateTime( $itemNuevo->fechaentrega );

            $interval_now       = $fechaSistema->diff($diaEntrega);
            $interval_inicial   = $diaInicial->diff($diaEntrega);

            $dias_restantes = $interval_now->format('%R%a');
            // he dejado esta variable pero no la utilozo
            // creo que se podria prescindir
            $total_dias     = $interval_inicial->format('%R%a');


            // el bucle no se muy bien para que es
            /*
            while ($diaInicialForm != $fechaSistemaForm){
                    if ($diaInicialForm->dayOfWeek != 0 && $diaInicialForm->dayOfWeek != 6) $dias++;
                    $diaInicialForm->addDay();
                }
            */

            /*
            esto seguramente te de error, 
            $itemNuevo deberia ser accedido como un objeto no como un array 
            */ 
            $itemNuevo["dias_restantes"] = $dias;

            // directamente comparamos los dias que restan 
            if ( $dias_restantes < 0)
            {
                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->records  = $registros;
                $this->message  = "Ya no tiene garantia";
                $this->result   = true;
            }

            /* 
            no necesistas anidar los if 
            puedes utilizar elfeif(){}
            */
            elseif ( $dias_restantes == 0)
            {
                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->records  = $registros;
                $this->message  = "La garantia vence hoy";
                $this->result   = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->records  = $registros;
                // concatenamos los dias que restan
                $this->message  = "Queda ".$dias_restantes." dias de garantia";
                $this->result   = true;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $statusCode     = 200;
        $this->message  = "Error en el registro.";
        $this->result   = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        $response =
        [   /*
            message, result, records 
            estas 3 variables tendran solo los valores del ultimo ciclo
            */ 
            'message' => $this->message,
            'result'  => $this->result,
            'records' => $this->records
        ];
            return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente muchisimas gracias. !!